# Suppress CA1303 fxcop warning when constructing a new Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fxcop

When I throw an exception in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 code, fxcop warns me when it sees a string literal as an argument to a `new Exception()`. For example:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException("Ouch");
```

gives me `CA1303: Do not pass literals as localized parameters`

As a general rule, I don't display exception messages to end users, so I have no desire to localize them. Is there a way to configure CA1303 so that it ignores constructor arguments on anything that derives from `System.Exception`?

EDIT:

After a bit more searching, I've found this conversation about exactly this problem:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3.3.0 of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` finally fixed the ability to suppress the warning when calling specific types.

In order to suppress CA1303 when constructing an `Exception` or when calling an `ILogger` function, I added a `.editorconfig` file to the root directory of my solution (all of the projects are subdirectories of this directory) and added these lines to it:

```
[*.cs]
dotnet_code_quality.CA1303.excluded_type_names_with_derived_types = Exception|LoggerExtensions|ILogger
```

This tells CA1303 to ignore calls into `Exception`, `LoggerExtensions`, and `ILogger` (and any type that derives from these types).

For reference, see this issue and the reply beneath it:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2933#issuecomment-627256340

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .editor config, you could do this: `dotnet_code_quality.CA1303.use_naming_heuristic = true`
Or completely disable CA1303.

Comment: Been there, tried that, doesn't work. May be related to the fact that the `.editorconfig` code editor complains that `The keyword "dotnet_code_quality.CA1303.use_naming_heuristic" is unknown`.

Comment: You can add the following to your csproj: `<NoWarn>CA1303</NoWarn>`